# Current user location is not shown (Blue Dot)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, mkmapview, cllocation

I am trying to do very basic thing in an existing project to show user location (Blue Dot) and do location update. I have all delegate methods, settings are on for show user location and I can make it work in new project.

Although I am using real device it is not asking me that "do you want to use location services in this app?" or under security->location services I can't see my application next to others. Howvever when I checked `[CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled];` it returns YES.

I have also tried it with simulator and virtual location San Francisco. Same result, no even blue dot.

One tip. This project was started to build about 2 years ago and now I am setting deployment target to 7.1.

Any help will be appreciated.

Some code I ve used may help:

in viewDidLoad

```
mapCheckinAcity.delegate = self;
[mapCheckinAcity setMapType:MKMapTypeStandard];
[mapCheckinAcity setZoomEnabled:YES];
[mapCheckinAcity setScrollEnabled:YES];
mapCheckinAcity.showsUserLocation = YES;

self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
BOOL bl = [CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled];
self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
self.locationManager.delegate = self;
[self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

Comment: Add some code for checking what problem in your code.

Comment: I ve added some code.

Comment: Add your viewforannotation method code.

Comment: it is not even called.

Comment: are you run your application in simulator or device ?

Comment: as I stated in the question I am running in both.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56521/discussion-between-darshan-kunjadiya-and-gbesler).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

CLLocationCoordinate2D location = [self geoCodeUsingAddress:str];

```
location.latitude = (double) location.latitude;

location.longitude = (double) location.longitude;

MKCoordinateSpan span;

span.latitudeDelta=40.01;

span.longitudeDelta=40.01;

MKCoordinateRegion region = {location,span};

MapAnnotation *newAnnotation = [[MapAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:location];

[self.mapview addAnnotation:newAnnotation];

[mapview setRegion:region];

[self.view addSubview:mapview];
```

Comment: Not helping this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling Location Services in iOS settings

Settings > Privacy > Location Services > and  enable access for your application